# Синтаксис (Помогите пожалуйста ответить на вопрос)

Tags: синтаксис

Объясните, вследствие чего необходимо при квалификации вида подчинительной синтаксической связи учитывать синтаксическую функцию зависимого компонента словосочетания?

Answer (score 3):

При определении подчинительной связи в словосочетании обязательно учитываю морфологическую (частеречную) характеристику зависимого слова. О том, что необходимо учитывать синтаксическую функцию - слышу впервые. Например, какая разница, каким членом предложения является существительное? Если зависимое слово - существительное, вид подчинительной связи - управление.